# Invalid Arguments in Razor DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm receiving an error that a dropdownlist has invalid arguments.  What's odd is that I have a similarly structured dropdownlist that is working fine, with no errors.  The drop down with the error is the second one (that displays the year):

View:

```
@{
                        string month = "TempEmployments[" + idx + "].EmploymentStartMonth";
                        string year = "TempEmployments[" + idx + "].EmploymentStartYear";
                     }
                    @Html.DropDownList(month, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.MonthList,EmploymentStartMonth, new { @class = "field panel-field EmploymentDate", @id = month })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmploymentStart)
                    @Html.DropDownList(year, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.YearList, EmploymentStartYear, new { @class = "field panel-field EmploymentDate", @id = year })
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmploymentHistory(int ApplicantID, int RecordNum)
    {
        this.ViewBag.RecordNum = RecordNum;
        this.ViewBag.StateList = this.GetStateList();
        this.ViewBag.MonthList = this.GetMonthList();
        this.ViewBag.YearList = this.GetYearList();
        return PartialView("_EmploymentHistoryPartial");
    }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetYearList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> yearList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        int current_yr = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        int select_yr = 0;
        for(int i = (current_yr-3); i <= current_yr; i++)
        {
            select_yr = current_yr - (i - (current_yr-3));
            yearList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = select_yr.ToString(), Text = select_yr.ToString() });
        }
        return yearList;
    }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMonthList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> monthList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JAN", Text = "Jan" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "FEB", Text = "Feb" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "MAR", Text = "Mar" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "APR", Text = "Apr" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "MAY", Text = "May" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JUN", Text = "Jun" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JUL", Text = "Jul" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "AUG", Text = "Aug" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "SEP", Text = "Sep" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "OCT", Text = "Oct" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "NOV", Text = "Nov" });
        monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "DEC", Text = "Dec" });
        return monthList;
    }
```

Comment: downvoting a question without explanation is pointless.  i have no idea what was "incorrect" or "bad" with my question.

Comment: I would imagine the downvote is due to the lack of information. I thought you hadn't included the error until I read the title. More information on the exception (including the inner exception) are very helpful for these kinds of questions.

Comment: I agree that the error would have been nice. I also agree down votes without explanation is pointless. The original question included his code which is a great start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a sample project with the data you provided and came up with this :

**Controller**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            this.ViewBag.RecordNum = 1;
            this.ViewBag.MonthList = this.GetMonthList();
            this.ViewBag.YearList = this.GetYearList();
            return PartialView();
        }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetYearList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> yearList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            int current_yr = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
            int select_yr = 0;
            for (int i = (current_yr - 3); i <= current_yr; i++)
            {
                select_yr = current_yr - (i - (current_yr - 3));
                yearList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = select_yr.ToString(), Text = select_yr.ToString() });
            }
            return yearList;
        }

        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMonthList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> monthList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JAN", Text = "Jan" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "FEB", Text = "Feb" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "MAR", Text = "Mar" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "APR", Text = "Apr" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "MAY", Text = "May" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JUN", Text = "Jun" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "JUL", Text = "Jul" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "AUG", Text = "Aug" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "SEP", Text = "Sep" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "OCT", Text = "Oct" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "NOV", Text = "Nov" });
            monthList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "DEC", Text = "Dec" });
            return monthList;
        }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    //string month = "TempEmployments[" + idx + "].EmploymentStartMonth";
    //string year = "TempEmployments[" + idx + "].EmploymentStartYear";
}
@Html.DropDownList("some name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.MonthList,"some label", new { @class = "field panel-field EmploymentDate", @id = "id" })
<!-- @@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmploymentStart) No idea what your model is-->
@Html.DropDownList("some name2", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.YearList, "some label", new { @class = "field panel-field EmploymentDate", @id = "id2" })
```

And both dropdowns in my test worked 100% fine. This makes me believe that one either id, name, or label are not being populated correctly. The code you provided does not show how their values are created

Populate your second dropdown just like mine (with a dummy id, label, and name, and see if it renders. Then by process of elimination add them back in.

Also, just a general tip, I would be abstracting those classes out of your controller and into their own classes. Helps keep things a lot cleaner. As well as pass in viewmodels with all of your properties needed. This avoids "Magic strings" and allows code to be easier to update and debug.

As example instead of  :

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            this.ViewBag.RecordNum = 1;
            this.ViewBag.MonthList = this.GetMonthList();
            this.ViewBag.YearList = this.GetYearList();
            return PartialView();
        }
```

I would do

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new indexViewModel{
            RecordNum = 1,
            MonthList = _someService.GetMonthList(),
            YearList = _someService.GetYearList()
            }
            return PartialView(viewModel);
        }
```

then in your view you don't have to worry about magic strings. you can simply do

```
@Model.MonthList
```

Comment: I was able to find the problem using your solution.  I had defined EmploymentStartYear as int, while EmploymentStartMonth is string.  Changing the int to string fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if I had to guess it has to do with a viewbag being used for a partial view after the page load.  Viewbag has its uses but it isn't recommended for drop downs.  I would recommend that you build a view model for your partial

```
public Class EmploymentHistory{
    public EmploymentHistory(){
        StateList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        MonthList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        YearList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public string RecordNum { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StateList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedState { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MonthList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedMonth { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> YearList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedYear { get; set; }
}
```

then on your controller instead of setting the view bag set the model

```
EmploymentHistory eh = new EmploymentHistory();
eh.StateList = GetStateList();
etc...
```

and you can set the defaults for the dropdowns on the controller

```
eh.SelectedState = //Default value;
return PartialView("_EmploymentHistoryPartial", eh);
```

on the top of your partial

```
@model EmploymentHistory
```

and then change your dropdowns to

```
@Html.DropDownList(SelectedState, model.StateList, new { @class...
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, model.StateList, new { @class...
```

Comment: He claims the first dropdown works though so I don't believe it would be a problem with the viewbag and a partial. Though I agree that it is best in a viewModel.